# Where does firefox store the data whether an extension is enabled or disabled?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to automate the process of creating a Firefox profile. I want to create a profile that is in a exact desired state that I want for various tasks, this desired state can something such as

1. A relatively clean profile
2. A specific set of settings in the `\prefs.js` file, such as disabling the "Make Firefox your go-to browser" first time launch dialog
3. A specific set of `css` settings in the `chrom` directory, just to visually differentiate the profile from others
4. A specific set of extensions
5. All extensions are always enabled

and so on, I have figured out most things but for the life of me I cant figure out item **.5**, when I start the profile, all extensions are always disabled and I have to manually enable them
I tried figuring out what file this information is stored on but have had no luck. Does anyone know?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're on windows?

The physical location of your extensions is located at:

1. Open the Run menu from the Windows Start Menu
2. Open %appdata%
3. Open Mozilla
4. Open Firefox
5. Open Profiles
6. Open the folder inside of the Profiles folder
7. Open Extensions

There's a further flag contained within firefox itself that dictates which extensions are in an "enabled" state. That is to say, there's a store contained within the application itself that has a true/false flag for each. It used to be accessible through their extension api.

If you can provide more detail as to what you want, I can likely steer you more precisely; I've written extension managers for both FF and GC before.

Comment: Yes I am on windows, you were right it was the `extension.json` file that I needed to modify. I need the following, under each extension: `"visible": true,`, `"active": true,`, `"userDisabled": false,` and `"appDisabled": false,`. Thank you.